# cloud run deployment pattern when new images are pushed, if services are created via terraform, is it avoidable?

Tags: terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-cloud

I have a set of cloud run services created/maintained via terraform cloud.

When I create a new version, a github actions workflow pushes a new image to gcr.io.

Now in a normal scenario, I'd call:

```
gcloud run deploy auth-service --image gcr.io/riu-production/auth-service:latest
```

And a new version would be up. If I do this and the resource is managed by terraform, on the next run, terraform apply will fail saying it can't create that cloud run service due to a service with that name already existing. So it drifts apart in state and terraform no longer recognizes it.

A simple solution is to connect the pipeline to terraform cloud and run `terraform apply -auto-approve` for deployment purposes. That should work.

The problem with that is I really realy don't want to apply terraform commands in a pipeline, for now.

And the biggest one is I really would like to keep terraform out of the deployment process altogether.

Is there any way to force cloud run to take that new image for a service without messing up the terraform infrastructure?

Cloud run configs:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "auth-service" {
  name     = "auth-service"
  location = var.gcp_region
  project  = var.gcp_project

  template {
    spec {
      service_account_name = module.cloudrun-sa.email
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.gcp_project}/auth-service:latest"
      }
    }
  }
  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }


}
```

Comment: So you understand the consequences "drifts apart in state and terraform no longer recognizes it." and you still don't want to do `terraform apply`, can you explain why?

Comment: `keep terraform out of the deployment process` are you planning to replace it with some other infrastructure as code tool?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda initially, it seems a bit risky running an `apply` in CI, what if a junior wipes out the whole database? That's scenario is my main concern, although for now I'm looking at implementing the terraform-friendly solution.

Comment: That scenario applies to all not just junior, you should have your code in a code repo that does not allow direct merge but you enforce changes  via Pull Requests and reviews are required before merge is allowed

Comment: That's fair enough and already applied, together with changesets and a few other tools like husky & branch protection. But nonetheless, I'll make another SO thread about this cloud run specific deployment issue via terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory yes it should be possible ...
But I would recommend against that, you should be doing terraform apply on every deployment to guarantee the infrastructure is as expected.

Here are some things you can try:

- Keep track of when it changes and use the import on that resource:
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#import
- Look into lifecycle ignore, you can ignore the attribute that triggers the change:
  https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes

Comment: Thank you for this -- I've been actually researching how to do it via `terraform apply` since then as suggested. My current source is `gcr.io/${var.gcp_project}/auth-service:latest` -- the issue is when running apply after pushing a new image and tagging it with `:latest` terraform will not detect any changes and a new deployment will not happen. 

Do you know of a way to get it to change? I've been reading blob posts/docs and other  threads about this but no luck.